data fetching using foreign key from database using mongodb, nodejs, reactnative expo
I have booking schema and i tried to fetch data from this booking database when userid that fetched from the secureStore  and tenant_id are matches and the approval field is 'accepted'.
problem:it show me  ERROR  Error fetching bookings: [Error: HTTP error! Status: 404] this error several times
approaches: i tried just with when the approval field is accepted and it works
this is my codes
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const bookingSchema = new Schema(
  {
    property_id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "property",
      required: true,
    },
    tenant_id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "user",
      required: true,
    },
    owner_id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "user",
      required: true,
    },
    start_date: { type: String, required: true },
    end_date: { type: String, required: true },
    approval: { type: String, default: "Pending" },
    message: { type: String },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Booking = mongoose.model("Booking", bookingSchema);

module.exports = Booking;

//The end point

app.get("/bookings/:tenantId", async (req, res) => {
  const { tenantId } = req.params;

  try {
    const bookings = await Booking.find({
      tenant_id: tenantId,
      approval: "accepted",
    });

    if (!bookings || bookings.length === 0) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ message: "No accepted bookings found for this tenant." });
    }

    res.status(200).json(bookings);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching bookings:", error);
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ message: "Internal Server Error", error: error.message });
  }
});

//client side code
const [bookings, setBookings] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserId = async () => {
      try {
        const userId = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("user_id");
        if (!userId) {
          setError("User ID not found");
          return null;
        }
        return userId;
      } catch (err) {
        setError("Error fetching user ID");
        console.error("Error fetching user ID:", err);
        return null;
      }
    };

    const fetchBookings = async (userId) => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `http://10.139.165.187:8000/bookings/${userId}`
        );
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        setBookings(data);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(`Error fetching bookings: ${err.message}`);
        console.error("Error fetching bookings:", err);
      }
    };

    const getUserIdAndFetchBookings = async () => {
      const userId = await fetchUserId();
      if (userId) {
        await fetchBookings(userId);
      }
    };

    getUserIdAndFetchBookings();
  }, []);

i just want to fetch booking data when userid from securestore that match with the tenant_id of the booking schema and the the approval field ='accepted'
